# Sort product by stock

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a product collection and my code look like this

```
       $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
        ->addAttributeToSelect('groupdeal_fineprint')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('groupdeal_highlights')
        ->addStoreFilter()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds))
        /*->addAttributeToFilter('groupdeal_status', Devinc_Groupdeals_Model_Source_Status::STATUS_RUNNING)*/
        ->joinField('groupdeals_id','groupdeals/groupdeals','groupdeals_id','product_id=entity_id',null,'left')
        ->joinField('inventory_in_stock', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'is_in_stock', 'product_id=entity_id','is_in_stock>=0', 'left')
        ->joinField('position','groupdeals/groupdeals','position','product_id=entity_id',null,'left')
        ->setOrder('groupdeals_id','desc')
        ->setOrder('on_top','asc');
```

When i remove setOrder('on_top','asc') everything works perfect but if i place that code my products doesnt display. Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below code after collection

```
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
   array('stock_qty' => $this->getTable('cataloginventory/stock_status')),
  'e.entity_id = stock_qty.product_id AND stock_qty.website_id='.Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId(),
   array(
    'salable' => 'stock_qty.stock_status',
    'qty' => 'stock_qty.qty'
   )
   )->order('qty DESC');
```

Comment: Well got an error after adding that

Comment: Which error are you getting. Also, place the code which you have added.

Comment: i just added  the code after the code block i posted,